# Android Creating custom dimension in google analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics

I want to set user level custom variables using google analytics in android
I can see there is lack of documentation and demo for this I want to know how to set custom variable using GA and I am referring to following link

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828#scope

but it is not helpfull at all code given in it is not in java and very confusing
If anyone has proper sample related to it please share

And it is not clear at all how much time it will take to reflect these changes on GA dashboard there is no clarity while using google analytics.

Also there a sample a code given

```
// Get tracker.
Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
t.setScreenName("Home Screen");

// Send the custom dimension value with a screen view.
// Note that the value only needs to be sent once.
t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder()
    .setCustomDimension(1, "premiumUser")
    .build()
);
```

Now can anyone explain what is value 1 stands and it comes from where for in above call and why I need to call setScreenName

Also I have referred below link as well but does not give any clear idea

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en&ref_topic=2709827

Also I tried to create custom variable I observed that one custom variable Demographic is already there I guess it is default created by GA so now my custom variable will start with index 2 or 1 that is also a confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Custom Dimensions and metrics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828#scope) are identified by an index: 1 to n. The first Custom dimension you create will have an index of 1. Before you can send custom dimension and metric values to Analytics, they must first be defined in an Analytics property in the Analytics UI or through the [Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/customDimensions/insert). Each Analytics property has 20 available indices for custom dimensions, and another 20 indices available for custom metrics.

The sample you used is sending a screen view hit (hence why it is setting the screen name) and sending a value to the first custom dimension. However you can send the information on any [event type](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/events) you'd like. For example:

```
// Get tracker.
Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
    TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
// Build and send an Event.
t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
    .setCategory(getString(categoryId))
    .setAction(getString(actionId))
    .setLabel(getString(labelId))
    .setCustomDimension(1, "premiumUser") // Set the first custom dimension value to premiumUser for this event.
    .build());
```

When you query for the value of the custom dimension with the [Analytics Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) you will identify the [custom dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=custom_variables_or_columns&jump=ga_dimensionxx) by index aswell, `ga:dimension1`.

Comment: Already one custom param is there Demographic so my custom dimension will be 1 or 2

Comment: Call [customdimensions.list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/customDimensions/list#try-it) and know for sure. The first custom dimension you create will be `1/ ga:dimension1` the second will be `2/ ga:dimension2`.

Comment: Hi Matt I also wanted to know do i need to setCustomDimension every time I call send event or just once at start with any event will work as well.

Comment: I think that depends on the [scope](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828#example-hit) of the custom dimension. `HIT` scoped custom dimensions need to be sent for every event they need to be recorded with. For `SESSION` scoped custom dimensions you need only send it once per session. For `USER` scoped custom dimension as long as you are using [user id](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662) you need only send it once per user (or if the value changes). But if you are using the custom dimension as pseudo user id then it will need to be sent at least once per session.

Comment: Actually scenario is I have a uniques user id associated with every user and I want to associate it with event and unique id changes only if user clear data or user re-installs app so in this case can I send it once with any event ?

Comment: I don't know the exact model around clearing data and re-installing an application (does the [`cid`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cid) get reset?), you should only need to send the user scoped custom dimension once per session, attached to any event. The model is this: A user can have multiple sessions, A session can have multiple events. All events will be associated with a particular session, all sessions will be associated to a particular user. As always never send any **PII** as a user id.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from registering in Android

```
Bundle().apply {
  putString("Business", "NONE")
  putString("PageVertical", "NONE")
  FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context).setDefaultEventParameters(this)
}
```

Do not forget to register at Google Analytics UI

> Custom parameters: Custom parameters can be used as dimensions or metrics in Analytics reports. You can use custom dimensions for non-numerical event parameter data and custom metrics for any parameter data better represented numerically. Once you've logged a custom parameter using the SDK, register the dimension or metric to ensure those custom parameters appear in Analytics reports. Do this via: Analytics > Events > Manage Custom Definitions > Create Custom Dimensions

[Read more](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=android#log_events)

[image: Firebase Analytics UI]