# Firebase Permission Issue

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I have recently moved to Google's Firebase for the purpose of app analytics. But, I'm having trouble tracking my "log events" on the web console. Despite having the Owner permission, I'm unable to see anything under the "EVENTS" tab of the console.

Stack trace that I'm getting on the console on clicking the "EVENTS" tab.

```
js.js:162 Error: permissions undefined on currentAccess
    at Error (native)
    at ga49n.all
```

(https://ssl.gstatic.com/analytics/20160609/app/js/js.js:1870:630)
    at ga49n.fetch (https://ssl.gstatic.com/analytics/20160609/app/js/js.js:1870:730)
    at Object.c (https://ssl.gstatic.com/analytics/20160609/app/js/js.js:1919:2644)
    at Object.invoke (https://ssl.gstatic.com/analytics/20160609/app/js/js.js:85:376)
    at k (https://ssl.gstatic.com/analytics/20160609/app/js/js.js:435:2280)
    at j (https://ssl.gstatic.com/analytics/20160609/app/js/js.js:435:2484)
    at https://ssl.gstatic.com/analytics/20160609/app/js/js.js:435:3108
    at o.resolve (https://ssl.gstatic.com/analytics/20160609/app/js/js.js:435:3192)
    at t (https://ssl.gstatic.com/analytics/20160609/app/js/js.js:435:14766) undefined

All help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are aware of this issue and it should be fixed shortly.

Comment: Thank @Steve for the prompt answer. For the time being I'm able to track my events with my colleague's login but the Events tab just shows the number of events triggered (count of the logEvent api). Where do I see the full JSON key-value pairs that I am sending in the event?

Comment: Please see the response to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507941/firebase-analytics-custom-events-params

Comment: Thanks a lot @Steve. I'll try this out.

Comment: Console permission issue fixed. Thanks Firebase Team.