# Parameters for the Firebase event VIEW_ITEM isn't displayed (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to track an event with Firebase Analytics using VIEW_ITEM https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event.html#constants

```
  //EVENT select POST
  FIRAnalytics.logEvent(withName: kFIREventViewItem, parameters: [
        kFIRParameterItemID :"post",
        kFIRParameterItemName :(self.post?.title)!,
        kFIRParameterItemCategory :"post",
        kFIRParameterQuantity : UserDefaults.standard().integer(forKey: "nbReadPost")
  ])
```

I can see the event displayed in the data, but when I click on it to see more details, all the data about the parameters (name, category, quantity...) aren't displayed. I have just the default data.

However I don't use custom parameters.

(FYI : my account is linked to big query)

[image: screenshot1]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507941/firebase-analytics-custom-events-params

Comment: I have already seen it. But my event IS NOT a custom event. Its parameters are not custom parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase does currently not support parameter reports for view_item, this can be read here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/W9w-YKkW4fc

They are planning a support...

Answer (score 2):

After struggling with this same problem for over a week using `VIEW_ITEM` and finding no documentation about it I decided to move on to using `SELECT_CONTENT`.

Apparently only `SELECT_CONTENT` displays parameters (`content_type` and `content_id`) information on the dashboard.