# Firebase Analytic Search_Term Param value not showing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I want to log user search event to Firebase but the Search_Term param value in the Search event doesn't show up in the dashboard. Here my code:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SEARCH_TERM, searchText);
                mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SEARCH, bundle);
```

I have tried to log different event with other param and the param value show up in dashboard correctly!

How can I fix this? Thank you

Comment: Please refer to the answer to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507941/firebase-analytics-custom-events-params

Comment: @Steve Games Search event and Search_Term param is one of that suggested event

Comment: Currently, parameter reporting is offered only on a *subset* of suggested events.

Comment: @Steve Ganem Oh I see. Where can I find this subset list?

Comment: what is that sublist

Comment: "Subsets" are the same as the parameters seen in the right column at https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317498 . (Though @LKH is doing it correctly for the search shown in the question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Currently the search data doesn't appear in the Firebase Analytics dashboard.**

Your logging seems indeed correct. To see the data you can [use Google BigQuery](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765).

One thing you should do is to **ensure that `searchText` is 36 characters or less, otherwise data will just appear as empty in Firebase** (and BigQuery).

In general when struggling with data not appearing one should ensure that the logged events follows the possible combinations of events/parameters as described in https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317498 . Also notice that the Firebase Console doesn't show the data instantly after being logged (give it at least 30 minutes).

**Update:**

Firebase Analytics have later **increased the maximum length of event names and parameter name to 40 characters, and the maximum length of string parameter values to 100 characters**: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#wzxhzdk4version_100_-_november_21_2016wzxhzdk5

Comment: Where did you find the documentation about 36 characters or less or it will be empty? That seems like a very important detail that I have never seen in the Firebase documentation.

Comment: @P1X3L5: It's easy to miss. I couldn't find it in the docs for Android now, but in the API reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Param . (The limit has been increased now.)