# How to log event parameters to Firebase console

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have just started using Firebase for my app's analytics and I'm having some issues trying to view custom parameters associated with my events.

The problem is that when creating an audience, I can see all the events but cannot drill down to the parameters (no parameters are shown associated to the events)

As an example, I'd like to register the event "Add retail to favourite" and pass, as a parameter, the ID of the retail. The final goal is to assess how many users had added a certain retail to their favourite list.

For iOS I'm using this piece of code:

```
[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:@"add_retail_to_favorite" parameters:@{@"id_retail":idRetail}];
```

And for Android:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, String.valueOf(mId));
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("pv_detail", bundle);
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, all custom parameters are available in the BigQuery export. Not all the custom parameters are available in the standard reports in the console.

For more details, see
[Firebase Analytics custom events params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507941/firebase-analytics-custom-events-params)

We are looking for ways of improving the reports, and better support custom parameters is something we are considering.

Comment: Update: Custom Parameters can be viewed in dashboard now!