# Logging Firebase events in Android

Tags: android, firebase, analytics, firebase-analytics

I integrated Firebase with my Android app and logged a few events.
The logcat reports it as:

```
Event recorded: Event{appId='com.example.appid', name='screenView', params=Bundle[{pageName=pageForgotUsername, _o=app}]}

Event recorded: Event{appId='com.example.appid', name='screenView', params=Bundle[{pageName=pageLogin, _o=app}]}

Event recorded: Event{appId='com.example.appid', name='screenView', params=Bundle[{pageName=pageQuickSetup, _o=app}]}
```

How can I view the values of **pageName** on Firebase console? All I see is **screenView** in events.

Do we need 10 different devices to view data for any audience?

Comment: Please refer to the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507941/firebase-analytics-custom-events-params) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456358/how-to-log-event-parameters-to-firebase-console/38465412#38465412)

Comment: @mkwongh2g2: To conclude i can view custom parameters using Big Query only. Creating a new Audience is not an option. Is my understanding correct?