# Firebase Analytics events dont show values

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am new in Firebase and I am trying to understand it, I want to track whitch achievements( by my id) my users unlocks

I saw lot of post about this like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507941/firebase-analytics-custom-events-params) where it says

> Currently, parameter reporting is offered only on a subset of suggested events. If you need to access your custom parameters, you can link your app to BigQuery and run queries on the raw data there.

So as far as I understand, It should show the values of the suggested events,but I dont even get that values, I am getting the events but not the values, My console shows no values.

I am doing something bad on the code? I am misunderstanding events? Or is Firebase not working as it should?

Code sending to firebase my id

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ACHIEVEMENT_ID, Integer.toString(lm.logros[a].id));
 mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.UNLOCK_ACHIEVEMENT, bundle);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For accessing all the data(in your case the values part) that you log in Firebase Analytics.. you have to link firebase to use Google Big Query service that's not available for Free.

Comment: That is nasty from google, so you need to pay in order to use events, thank you very much for your answer

Comment: you can still hack around userProperty ;)

Comment: can you please give some example ( even verbal is ok) of "how to do it"

Comment: you create userProperty in firebase Console (max 20, can't be changed) for the achievements then setUserProperty(achievement,"achieved"/"not_achieved")