# Firebase analytics not give Custom events details instead (total) 0 items

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I implemented firebase in the application. I created an event and it was shown on logs. I have also Registered event parameters on the Event screen, there it was showing (total) 0 items.

Code:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();   
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE,"NetworkShare01");    
bundle.putInt(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, 1);    
bundle.putString("Shared_text", "Here just a text in Hebrew language");    
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("Shared_app",bundle);
```

Logs:

```
Shared_app, Bundle[{Shared_text=Here just a text in Hebrew language,     
firebase_event_origin(_o)=app, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=Message,     
firebase_screen_id(_si)=5901034026982773896, content_type=NetworkShare01,     
item_id=1}]
```

Comment: @peeebeee Thanks for formatted the post . But I am still figure it out what changes you have made and let me know what is the issue or step have forgot to make in this analytic issue

Comment: No one here to answer of this above question????

Comment: refer this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/40485207/1848157

Comment: @Radhey in this link there mentioned that project need to link with BigQuery. But it does not need actually. Event shown on StreamView and day after it shows on Event page and registered parameters to see their details. In Events details after register of parameters also showing Counters , User . But not shows value of event instead of (not set) .

Comment: Did you check this? https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489, moreover hope you enable analytics in debugmode

Comment: @Radhey I have already gone through this process that mentioned in above link that you shared and this is actually way to register the parameters of event . I did the same already and that's why it being shown on Events graph like counters and users . But not show text that have sent . I can show screenshot as well, not aware how to do that over here. Badly stuck with this .

Comment: @Radhey , Thanks buddy  :) :) for reply and giving your opinions on this issue. But unfortunately issue could not be fix.

Answer (score 0):

Parameter reporting only works for data collected post creation. This means that it can take up to 24 hours before it shows any data.

For reference: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304?hl=en.

Comment: I have already done and this is the actual way to register the event parameters to see event details. But after registration it took a day then after it shows no data set but event was showing on Event console. I have already written above

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this :

`bundle.putInt(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, 1);`

To :

`bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, String.valueOf(1));`