# Add metrics to Firebase custom event

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-ab-testing

I'm trying to integrate with Firebase analytics, my goal is to create a custom event in a way when I will be able to apply Firebase OOTB metrics, like *customer retention*, or a custom metric to it.

I know that a Firebase event might be associated with predefined *User Property*.
Base on these *User Properties*  I'm able to perform simple queries on it.
Unfortunately it's not clear if I can apply a metrics to them, like if I would create a Firebase experiment with remote configuration.

I don't want to create a Firebase experiment (we have our custom solution to create an experiment). My purpose is to send our data to Firebase in a way I would be able to mimic the Firebase experiment.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40482478/how-to-add-firebase-custom-events-for-analytics

Comment: The link above is helpful although doesn't answer my question, I have to add a custom metric rather than a custom event.