# Firebase and Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I've integrated Firebase Analytics in my project but I encounter some issues:

- When I log an event, I don't have access to the value on the Dashboard. Apparently you have access to this information only if you use BigQuery (which is not free). In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38696288/1827254) they suggest a workaround using `setUserProperty` but first it's a bit messy, and second the userProperty accepts only a limited number of characters for its value so I can't use that.
- On Google Analytics, you have a `Behaviour Flow` where you can see how users is navigating through your app. I haven't been able to find a similar view on Firebase.

So I was thinking of using both. I've created a new property for my app in Google Analytics. As it's mobile only (no website) I've selected 'mobile app' for the property and Google Analytics asked me to link to my Firebase app.
I did so but now I have the exact same information on Google Analytics that I had on the Firebase Dashboard.

So what does it mean? Should I use both but in that case define my Google Analytics property as 'website' to not link it to Firebase? Can I achieve what I want (analysing custom event values and monitor the user flow through the app) using Firebase only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went down the same path as you, and finally started exporting to BigQuery and got exactly what I needed. I completely understand the desire for free, but I think you will be surprised at how inexpensive the "Blaze" plan is, since you only pay for what you use. We are logging about 250K Firebase events per day, which equates to US$0.03 per month (as of Dec 2017). The main cost is querying, which we do a LOT of (about 1.6TB per month) which costs about US$3 per month. Our total monthly bill is about US$3.50 per month.

Comment: Thank you for sharing these information. I'll have a look at it.