# What event should i use for sending a "button pressed" event on Firebase Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

The one I found most suitable is [SELECT_CONTENT](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event.html#SELECT_CONTENT), but as the doc says:

> Select Content event. This general purpose event signifies that a user has selected some content of a certain type in an app. The content can be any object in your app. This event can help you identify popular content and categories of content in your app.

I'm moving my GA events to FB and I wish to keep the comfortable format I have:
screen_name (category) | button_name (action) | value (opt_value)

How can I achieve this? I know I can just create custom events with the screen name and custom param for the button name and value but then my params won't be available in the FB dashboard unless I use the value param which is an int (I need a string) as [written here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507941/firebase-analytics-custom-events-params) and I'll need to **create from advance** an audience for every button so I could filter by it later, which is completely not making any sense (!).

Also, I don't want to integrate with BigQuery at the moment.

Thanks.

Comment: Great question and looking forward to a answer. Being able to understand user flows and user choices through an application (via button clicks) is a mandatory requirement for an analytics tool. Will stay with GA until an easy to use solution is articulated!

Answer (score 7):

The built-in Firebase Analytics events are structured more around key actions the user can take within the app. For example, there might be multiple buttons or UI widgets that could be used to share content, so these could be tied to the [SHARE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event.html#SHARE) event.

Therefore, I would recommend looking through the built-in events and using them where appropriate for any button presses you have.

If those don't suffice and you want to track more, the [SELECT_CONTENT](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event#SELECT_CONTENT) is quite a general purpose event that you can map in any way you see fit. For example, you could set the [CONTENT_TYPE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Param.html#CONTENT_TYPE) to say, "button" and [ITEM_ID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Param#ITEM_ID) to the name of the button. While this is not the main purpose of this event, it should work for what you're after.

The last and most flexible option is a custom event with custom params, however as you noted, only the VALUE param will show in the built-in Firebase dashboard so for this approach you would need to use BigQuery to retrieve the data and therefore not very useful for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can track click of a button like this:
(In my case, I have an InHouse Ad and I want to track number of clicks.)

```
public void openGoz(View view){
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.mountzoft.gameofzeros");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("goz_ad_click","1");
    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("in_house_ad_click", bundle);
}
```

Comment: Did you get the event on Dashboard?

Comment: Yes, but only in the production built after couple of days. I did get an immediate response. @RishabhRastogi

Comment: It will show the log events within the last 30 mins or is it custom? I am not able to see the events beyond the 30 mins range. Can you please shed some light on this?