# Button press event on Firebase Analytics

Tags: android, ios, swift, firebase, google-analytics

I know this looks like a silly question but I couldn't find any proper answer or documentation in the community.

I'm moving my project from Google Analytics to Firebase.
Now I'm sending button press analytics data with below code

```
guard let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker, let builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEvent(withCategory: "Button", action: "Interaction", label: "Log-In Button Pressed", value: NSNumber(integerLiteral: value ?? 0))
        else { return }

tracker.set(kGAIScreenName, value: "Log-in Page")
tracker.send(builder.build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

**My Question** is that where should I put my screen name and category on Firebase Analytics?

As I searched, Google limits events with 500. "Button_Pressed" can be used as a global event and screen name, etc can be parameters. However, I'm not sure If It will be the best approach.

**Second Question** is that as I searched, we can't use same event names with the ones Firebase provides itself. I know my custom event name isn't used by default on Firebase but how can I be sure that "Button_Pressed" won't be added ?

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317498?hl=en&ref_topic=6317484

How I'm thinking to log button event on Firebase:

```
Analytics.logEvent("Button_Pressed", parameters: [
  "screenName": "Log-in Screen",
  "event": "Log-in Button Pressed",
  "category": "Interaction"
  ])
```

What I searched so far

[What event should i use for sending a "button pressed" event on Firebase Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39635123/what-event-should-i-use-for-sending-a-button-pressed-event-on-firebase-analyti)