# How to use attributes?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

Is it possible to view attribute in the Firebase console, if I don't buy any plan? We are currently using free membership, and we might end up making use of attributes along with the event.

Is it possible to log attributes along with the event and see it on dashboard? Lastly, I could find out, we need to have link it to big Query and for that we need to buy a plan.

Comment: There is no difference in the analytics features that you see in the Firebase console between free and paid plans. Custom parameters are not shown in the console for anyone at the moment. They are only available when you export the detailed analytics data to BigQuery (which is only an option on the Blaze plan). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40738448/firebase-custom-event-parameters-not-visible-in-console

Answer (score 1):

You can use [User Property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/properties). Once you set a user property, it will always attach to any event until you explicitly remove it by setting it to null.

> You can access this data as follows:
>
> In the Firebase console, open your project. Select Analytics from the
>   menu to view the Analytics reporting dashboard. The User Properties
>   tab shows a list of user properties that you have defined for your
>   app. You can use these properties as a filter on many of the reports
>   available in Firebase Analytics. Read more about the Analytics
>   reporting dashboard in the Firebase Help Center.