# How to report parameters in Firebase Analytics Events

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, google-fabric

I've used `Fabric` with `iOS` before where it was so easy to report custom parameters in the same analytics event in like this:

```
Answers.logCustomEvent(withName: "saved_border", customAttributes: ["image_index":"\(index)"])
```

Now I'm trying to do the same with `Firebase Events` but I see only event names in console (without custom parameters)
Here my code:

```
Analytics.logEvent("saved_border",parameters: ["saved_image": index])
```

Is there any way creating same with `Firebase` except appending index to event name?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Now this is done using Custom Definitions in Firebase, according to this doc: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10075209

You need to go to Firebase Console and define Custom Definitions
[image]

After that and after you wait for 24hrs in Google Analytics you should be able to see this custom dimension with your custom event and custom parameters

[image]

Comment: I did what you indicate above one week ago, but the custom parameters are still disabled in google analytics include dimension.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: @PireneMartín I didn't wait that long for sure, so something is not right in your integration with Firebase. How do you send those custom events?

Comment: I can see the custom events and parameters in Firebase Analytics in Stream View menu.
In case of events menu, I only can see the custom params, not custom parameters.
The custom event I put them as custom dimension and the custom params as custom metrics. Is it ok?
In my case I use them in java android application.

Comment: You should take in consideration, that custom parameters that are string values should be defined as dimensions, and numeric values as metrics. This is quite confusing, but if you configure them differently, it will just simply not work.

Answer (score 16):

**[ UPDATE 2021 ]**

So it seems *Custom Definitions* has been moved to its own section in the side menu.

[image: Custom Definitions section in Firebase Console menu]

---

**[ UPDATE 2020 ]**

It is now done via something called *Custom Definitions*.

Refer to @ToM's answer for more or check: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10075209

---

**TL;DR**

You have to tell *Firebase* to start tracking that specific param for that specific event in the console.

---

In *Google Analytics for Firebase* there exists a limit on how many parameters you can add per event, and in total.
As of today, this limit is up to 100 parameters globally (50 numeric and 50 text).

That being said, because of having a limit, *Firebase* forces you to specify which parameters you want to be tracked, so in case you send more that 100 different parameters, you can still track the ones you decide, while excluding the others.
Only the parameters you explicitly specify to track are going to be shown in the *Firebase* console, so in order to start seeing that parameters, you will have to do the following:

1. Go to *Firebase* console
2. Go to *Events* section
3. Identify your event (`saved_border`in your case)
4. Click on the 3 dots icon for that parameter
5. Click on *Edit parameter reporting*
6. Finally add your parameter name `saved_image`

Once done, *Firebase* will start showing up that parameter for that event.

For more information about this, as well as the rest of the limitations regarding to custom params in events, *Google* explains it here: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304?hl=en

---

I think that this limitation only affects to the *Firebase* console, but not to *BigQuery*. So, although if you exceed the parameters limit, you will not see them in the console, I think that you could still access all those "missing" events and parameters via *BigQuery*, if you were using it and had it already linked with *Firebase*

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't so intuitive for me to tap this 3 dots :)

Comment: I can confirm that this limit is only for parameter reporting in Firebase UI, in BigQuery you will still see all your parameters

Comment: What if I don't have this option "Edit parameter reporting" when I click on three dots? I was able to see those custom parameters in live view, but now I'm unable to find them neither in Firebase nor in Analytics

Comment: @ToM Seems that Firebase has replaced Custom-Parameter Reporting with something called Custom Dimensions and Custom Metrics. This is why the option is no longer available and a new Manage Custom Definitions blue button has been added.
More info about this here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10075209

Comment: Yes, I found out about that. Currently I'm testing it.

Comment: I still didn't see the Manage Custom Definitions button in my console. Help please.

Comment: @AiraSamson I have updated the answer with the new location for Custom Definitions in the console

Comment: I just wanted to achieve like this https://console.firebase.google.com/u/4/project/fir-demo-project/analytics/app/android:com.labpixies.flood/events/~2Freport~2Flevel_fail%3Ft%3D1615712315389&fpn%3D300830567303&swu%3D1&sgu%3D1&sus%3Dupgraded&params%3D_u..pageSize%253D25%2526_r..eventId%253Dlevel_fail&cs%3Dapp.m.events.detail&r%3Ddefault&g%3D1, however I cannot see the defined custom parameters in my existing parameters.