# Reading Firebase custom event in Dashboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am trying to log custom events with Firebase. I want to log some long event description text with the event. I couldn't find in Firebase dashboard where to read `"full_text"` field. I can correctly find the `"name"` field but where is `"full_text"`?

```
[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"3: %@",response.description]
                            parameters:@{
                                         @"name": @"InAppPurchaseCrash1" ,
                                         @"full_text": @"Some description about the event log"
                                         }];
```

For example with this code I can see "InAppPurchaseCrash1" but not "Some description about the event log" in Firebase dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK tracking of custom parameters is currently not possible in the console. It is possible to track everything, when you connect Firebase to BigQuery, but that is not free and additional work.

There are some predefined event parameters you can use.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37511858/6637731) is an answer to a similar question, that explains the VALUE parameter.

Additionally, [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/topic/6317484?hl=en&ref_topic=6386699) you can find a list of predefined Firebase events. Some of them have predefined parameters. Maybe you can use one of the predefined events for your use case.

**Update**: I see, what you wanted to do was get more information about crash reporting. Note that Analytics and Firebase Crash should be used in different cases. Analytics is for normal common analytical events (someone bought something or clicked a link) and the Crash package is for excepional errors that you want to fix.

I don't know about IOS, but on Android FirebaseCrash has two important functions: log() and report() With report() you can report errors yourself and see them in the Firebase Console. log() on the other hand does not directly send anything to Firebase. But if there is an an Exception or you call report, the last log() calls will be sent together with the report (and you can see them in the console).

If you look in the [doumentation for IOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios) there is the FIRCrashLog(ObjC)/FIRCrashMessage(Swift) function that does what I described above. So IF there is an error, you will get the data logged with it together with your crash report.

Comment: How about FIRCrashLog? Is it possible to add some custom data to FIRCrashLog about the crash?

Comment: I don't know about IOS, but on Android FirebaseCrash has two important functions: log() and report()
With report() you can report errors yourself and see them in the Firebase Console. log() on the other hand does not directly send anything to Firebase. But if there is an an Exception or you call report, the last log() calls will be sent together with the report (and you can see them in the console).

Answer (score 0):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/events

```
 [FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:@"share_image"
                parameters:@{
                             @"name": name,
                             @"full_text": text
                             }];
```

- you can use custom parameters as well but it will log after 24 hours