# How to add custom content in firebase analytics android?

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

I am integrating FireBase analytics in android app when i registering app then show the custom event like e.g. login,logout events i want to add custom content in each event but does not show.but when i add in "select_content " then show perfectly so why not show in custom event?

I am adding content like as below

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "<params>");
params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "<params>");
params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "<params>");
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FireBaseConsts.LOGIN, "<params>");
```

How to add content in this, If anyone knows the answer please help me.

Thank in advance

Comment: I think this question has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507941/firebase-analytics-custom-events-params).

Comment: Thanx Dan Morenus it helped