# Cant get custom parameters in Firebase-Analytics with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-analytics

i hope you can help me. I use the Firebase Unity SDK 1.1.1 and Unity 5.5.0f3. I use Firebase-Analytics in my game to track different stuff. LogEvents without custom parameters get tracked well but if I try to add custom parameters i can't see the parameters in the Firebase Console.

For Example:

The following function get called every time the player open a Level and i can see this Event in the Console.
*Level_Played* is the name of the Event
*Level* is parameter name.
*currentLevel* is an integer value for the Level

```
Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent("Level_Played","Level", currentLevel);
```

If i try to create an audience to Filter this Event i can select *Level_Played* as an Event but can't select the parameter name *Level*. The list is just empty.

Hope you can help me

Comment: This question has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507941/firebase-analytics-custom-events-params)

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you won't be able to see the parameters of custom events according to the official documentation:

> Custom parameters: Custom parameters are not represented directly in
>   your Analytics reports, but they can be used as filters in audience
>   definitions that can be applied to every report. Custom parameters are
>   also included in data exported to BigQuery if your app is linked to a
>   BigQuery project.

Comment: thats right, but with a audience you should be able to filter it.

Comment: For predefined events, you will be able to see the parameters in Audience tab when creating new Audience. However, for custom events, you will need to manually type your custom parameters in Audience definition. Once there are results that match your audience (you may need at least 10 users), you should be able to see the number.