# Where can I see or filter event details in Firebase Analytics?

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

How can I display the bundle I send to analytics?

Here you can see the event I'm interested in:

[image: tutorial event statistics]

As you can see there are no details except of the value which didn't make sense for me.

However I know that the data are transmitted here is a Screenshot from a crash report:

[image: Crash report with bundle details]

Here you can see the parameter "tutorial_event" and "tutorial_page" which I am interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all event params are available in reporting.  However you can define audience filters that call out specific values and value ranges of params, and you can do more sophisticated processing in BigQuery.  See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507941/firebase-analytics-custom-events-params).