# How to Creating custom events for firebase analytics

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

I am completely new to firebase analytics, I have created custom event for firebase analytics but on console my custom events values is not display.
see my code 
[firebase console -> Custom Events "NEWS" , on click of NEWS user property nothing is display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUARW.png)

[code- analytics and set user property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHcyS.png)

For creating the custom user property we have set value or it automatically generated 
Please help me,
Thank You.

Comment: Custom events are currently not shown in the Firebase Analytics console. But they are transmitted and will be exported to BigQuery if you wire that up. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507941/firebase-analytics-custom-events-params

Comment: For future questions: please don't post (links to) screenshots with code (or other textual content). Instead post the actual text itself. If you mark it with the correct language, Stack Overflow will highlight it and it'll be much easier to see what you're doing.