# Firebase analytics, custom events values

Tags: android, bundle, firebase-analytics, custom-events

I'm trying to set some analytics in my app. The user can add 3 item to a list and I would like to know how much of valid item1, item2 and item the user has
moreover I also would like to know how many of expired item1, item2 and item3 it has. This is how I did it:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("valid_item1", validCount1);
 bundle.putInt("valid_item2", validCount2);
 bundle.putInt("valid_item3", validCount3);
 bundle.putInt("expired_item1", expireCount1);
 bundle.putInt("expired_item2", expireCount2);
 bundle.putInt("expired_item3", expireCount3);
 FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).logEvent("", bundle);
```

I was expecting to see in my Firebase analytics dashboard a diagram that shows me how much users have a valid_item1, valid_item2 etc...

Is this possible to accomplish? Or will I have to create 6 different events ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately Firebase does not display custom parameters on your events. You can still log them though and they are attached to that event. To view them you have to export to BigQuery.

See [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507941/firebase-analytics-custom-events-params).

Comment: what a shame. Does this mean I will have to do something like this?
bundle.putLong(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE, validItem1Count);
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).logEvent("valid_item_1", bundle);

Comment: I believe so. I think the limit on custom events is 500