# Post data from fragment to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm searching for a while how pass data from fragment to firebase console but i do not find something... I have seen how load data to fragment
I need to post a data of form inside a viewpager to firebase and to retreive them in an activity.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about passing data to Firebase Console.

Looks like you want to log a variable in your app that provides a collective data of all your users on Firebase Console's Analytics dashboard.

You can make use of the [custom events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events#log_events) that would let you log data pertaining to that variable on the Firebase console with the details each Firebase [event](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317522?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489) tracks.

Please note that [custom parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507941/firebase-analytics-custom-events-params) are not reported in Firebase Console directly and you need to have atleast 10 distinct users logging that event.

Comment: My issue is not about " having insight on what is happening in your app, such as user actions, system events, or errors". I  have a form in a bloging app inside viewpager fragments , and would that the  user entries variables (data) to be set in firebase and load back in activity