# Firebase Analytics: Event is shown without values

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, swift3, firebase-analytics

I am trying to use some of the events which are already predesigned in Firebase Analytics - e.g. the view_item. I implemented that like this:

```
Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventViewItem, parameters:
        [AnalyticsParameterItemCategory : "Test" as NSString,
         AnalyticsParameterItemName : ASINcode as NSString])
```

When I check debug view, it looks like this:[image]

The problem is, that I cannot find those parameters I attached in the Analytics Event - I see that it was triggered, but the ItemName is not available. If I go to "add event parameters" - it shows my parameters I attach, but after adding them as text, it looks like that:

[image]

I did this code already several days ago - so the delay should not be a problem. It also tracks the events, but the values are not there.

I already searched for some info on Stackoverflow and checked the tutorials and howto from firebase, but I don't really understand what is going wrong.

As shown in the tutorials, there should be automatic charts with the parameter values. I also checked that all not optional parameters are included.

I would be thankful for every advice or idea you can provide me with.

Answer (score 0):

DebugView is mostly for debugging so that's why you can see the parameters but the aggregation won't show the custom parameters unless you track them as described in this [help](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489) article. See [Firebase Analytics custom events params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507941/firebase-analytics-custom-events-params)